# converting 0 or 1 to yes or no in MVC4 model for display purposes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I will be displaying some results that will be either 0 or 1 in my MVC 4 application.  I would like for them to display either yes (1) or no (0).  Is there an annotation I can add to my fields to do that?  Or do I have to do that in the view somehow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the model, add a backing field and specify the getter for the property

```
private string _myString;
public string MyString
    {
        get
        {
            _myString = _myString.Equals( "0" ) ? "No" : "Yes";
            return _myString;
        }
        set { _myString = value; }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom HTML helper for this:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs

or perhaps just a plain extension method. I have one I use for Boolean values.

```
    public static bool ToYesNo(this Boolean boolValue)
    {
        return (boolValue ? "Yes" : "No");
    }
```

Comment: My values are strings coming out of the database already.  I just want them to display "yes", or "No"  Where do you call this extension method, and what is it extending?  Maybe the HTML helper will be the better route?